# Phonegap iOS input and contenteditable bug

Tags: html, ios, cordova, contenteditable

When clicking a div with the attribute contenteditable:

```
<div contenteditable>Try typing here</div>
```

or any input, the keyboard comes up, but the user cannot type.

Is this a bug in Phonegap 2.1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour was solved by removing the default line in CSS:

```
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the last Cordova's version (v5.1.1)

Answer (score 4):

This piece of Css works better with Cordova v5.1.1

```
*[contenteditable] {
    -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
}
```